# Tratando URL/string no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho que editar uma URL recebida, mas em alguns casos a URL pode conter uma referência externa com `http` e isso quebra meu sistema, pois ele só aceitava caminhos para a própria plataforma.

Segue um trecho de código e algumas saídas:

```
<%-object.each do |o| -%>
<%- url = @context.nil? ? polymorphic_path([ :adm, o]) : polymorphic_path([ :adm, @context, o])-%>
```

Algumas saídas:

```
<%= o -%> = #<Collection:0x7f068b067870>

<%= @context.nil? -%> = true

<%= polymorphic_path([ :adm, o]) -%> = /admin/pagina/biblioteca
```

Aqui que está o meu erro, às vezes este link pode ser externo, e quando concatena não consigo fazer funcionar:

```
<%= polymorphic_path([ :adm, o]) -%> = /admin/pagina/https://livraria.com
```

Acredito que esse retorno da variável `url` é uma String.

Comment: Pode inspecionar o valor da variável "o" ?

Comment: Já consegui solucionar, a variável "url" tem como retorno uma string e o ruby aceita expressões regulares. em breve postarei a RegEx utilizada.

Answer (score 1):

Vi que você já achou uma solução, mas se alguém tiver com dúvida similar, é só substituir o http ou https no link:

```
link.gsub(/https?\/\//, '')
```